# parse values in section blocks into the table view

Tags: python, parsing, text-processing, data-representation

I have the following structure in export file:

```
[item 1]
param1;value1
param2;value2
param3;value3
[sub-item 1.1]
param4;value4
param5;value5
[item 2]
param1;value1
param2;value2
param3;value3
[sub-item 2.1]
param4;value4
param5;value5
```

I would like to convert it to table view, similar to this:

```
itemX; param 1; param2; param3; param4; param5
item1; value 1; value2; value3; value4; value5
item2; value 1; value2; value3; value4; value5
...
```

After such conversion I'll be able to put data into XLS to make some analytics.
Thought of using Python and dictionaries, but can't find out how to read parameter values section by section, so item1 values are in one string/list/row, item2 is in next, etc...